# How to Save R-squared in sas?

Tags: sas, statistics, regression

I have the following sas code (last few lines). What I need is to save r-squared, adjusted r-squared (besides keeping CUSIP6 trandate CRSPtrandate tshares shrvol dolvol BSI intercept mktrf smb hml umd).

```
proc sort data=dailyFFrets;
    by CUSIP6 trandate CRSPtrandate tshares dolvol BSI shrvol;
run;

options nonotes;

proc reg data=dailyFFrets outest=alpha (keep=CUSIP6 trandate CRSPtrandate 
        tshares shrvol dolvol BSI intercept mktrf smb hml umd) noprint;
    by CUSIP6 trandate CRSPtrandate tshares dolvol BSI shrvol;
    model rirf=mktrf smb hml umd;
quit;

options notes;

data alpha;
    set alpha;
    alpha=intercept*sign(tshares)*100;
run;
```

Comment: Please see this post to answer your question: http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2017/01/09/ods-output-any-statistic.html

Answer (score 1):

This might help: http://support.sas.com/kb/22/640.html

> Use an ODS OUTPUT statement to save the table named FitStatistics to a data set. See this note for more on saving tables from procedures. For example,

```
   ods output FitStatistics = fitstats;
   proc reg data=in;
      model y = x;
      run;
```

> You can also specify the RSQUARE and EDF options in the PROC REG or
> MODEL statement to add R2 and the error degrees of freedom,
> respectively, to the OUTEST= data set. Requesting any additional
> statistic results in R2 being added to the OUTEST= data set.
>
> For example, if you specify the ADJRSQ option, then adjusted R2 (*ADJRSQ*)
> and R2 (*RSQ*) are added to the OUTEST= data set.